# ODBC in Go Returning Null/Blank Records

Tags: go, odbc, filemaker

I am trying to connect a Go REST API to a backend FileMaker based database over ODBC.

I have successfully installed the FileMaker ODBC drivers on Windows and the DSN is working.

I am using the `mgodbc` package in Go to connect to the DB.

However, while the connection works (no runtime error), I just get blank/null records back when I run a query. I have the following code to create a DB connection:

```
func NewDB(dataSourceName string) (*DB, error) {

    db, err := sql.Open("mgodbc", dataSourceName)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if err = db.Ping(); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // TEST

    return &DB{db}, nil
}
```

This gets called from my `main` method as follows: `db, err := md.NewDB("DSN=cet_registrations2;Uid=*****;Pwd=*****;")`. I then call one of my query methods and try to read it into a model `struct`. I have simplified my query to make it easier:

```
func (db *DB) GetStudent(id int) (*Student, error) {

    s := new(Student)
    p := new(PersonalDetails)

    log.Println(id)

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT FN_Gn_Pn FROM STUDENTS")

    i := 0
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
        i++
        err := rows.Scan(&p.FirstName)
        log.Print(p.FirstName.String)
        log.Printf(strconv.Itoa(i))
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
    err = rows.Err()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s.ID = 34114
    s.Details = p

    return s, err
}
```

and I am reading into the following `struct`:

```
import (
    "database/sql"

    u "sydney.edu.au/bric9018/cet.api/util"
)

type PersonalDetails struct {

    // Unique identifier for person
    ID int32 `json:"id,omitempty"`

    // First name of person
    FirstName sql.NullString `json:"firstName,omitempty"`

    // Last name of person.
    LastName sql.NullString `json:"lastName,omitempty"`

    // Person nominated preferrered name.
    PreferredName sql.NullString `json:"preferredName,omitempty"`

    // Person's SSO username for University systems
    Unikey sql.NullString `json:"unikey,omitempty"`

    // Person's personal email
    PersonalEmail sql.NullString `json:"personalEmail,omitempty"`

    // Sydney University email
    UniEmail sql.NullString `json:"uniEmail,omitempty"`

    // Person's date of birth
    Dob u.NullTime `json:"dob,omitempty"`
}
```

However, I just get completely blank rows when I print the value scanned into the model using `log.Print(p.FirstName.String)`. I don't seem to be getting any values read back by scan into my `struct`. Why is this?

P.S. the query definitely returns values when I run it in SQL Server over a linked server connection against the FileMaker DB.

Comment: What do you get if you scan the value into a variable having `[]byte` type instead of `sql.NullString`?

Comment: If I change it to `[]byte` and use the same print statement without the string (`log.Print(p.FirstName)`) I get no values in the array i.e. `[]` is printed.

Comment: How if you change the driver from `mgodbc` to [`odbc` driver](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc) (just change the import part)?

Comment: That has fixed it. Thank you so much. If you make it an answer, I am happy to make it the answer. It would be even better if you can offer any insight into what might have been wrong with the `mgodbc` driver so I can learn something about `odbc` drivers/`golang`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Golang odbc driver is a wrapper of system's odbc driver (`odbc32.dll, unixODBC`, etc). If you got any result when executing the query in SQL Server, it eliminates the probability of query error or system's driver problem. Then the problem will be in golang's driver (`mgodbc`) side. Possible issues:

1. The driver failed to convert query result due to mismatch/unsupported data type (e.g. you store the string in the database table as binary, etc). So the first try was `scan the result to []byte`.
2. The driver failed to convert query result due to bug. Try using [another odbc driver](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc).

Because the database in question is not available to us, its impossible for us to reproduce the problem. To learn what was the problem, please use debugger. Personally I'm using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/go). To setup the debugger, please refer to [VS Code and delve debugger](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Debugging-Go-code-using-VS-Code).

My guess, the problem exist in [`mgodbc's Next`](https://bitbucket.org/miquella/mgodbc/src/2207dbb576082c34dacb4e887357ecfa99e011d5/mgodbc.go?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) function (line number 781-1011). The `odbc's` implementation of `Next` function is available [here](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/blob/master/rows.go) (line 35). The function relies on [`column.Value`](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/blob/master/column.go) function (line 116-165) to convert the query result. Using debugger, you can observe variable(s), expression(s) and compare how these drivers handle query result conversion.